# RecyclerView is empty or not

Tags: android, mysql, android-recyclerview

How can I know if my `RecyclerView` is empty or not?
I want to show a dialog for user to show :
this part has nothing information

```
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_congress);
    data_list  = new ArrayList<>();
    load_data_from_server(0);
    gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(this,1);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);
    adapter = new CustomAdapter4(this,data_list);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: Your RecyclerView is 'empty' when the list you use to provide data to it, is empty. Avoid using a dialog, display a message directly where the RecyclerView is supposed to be displayed

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to detect if RecyclerView is empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27222140/how-to-detect-if-recyclerview-is-empty)

Answer (score 3):

You can check if your `adapter.getItemCount()` is returning 0. If its 0, then, your recyclerView has no items to show.

Comment: Thnaks for your help !! but this code always give zero. I do not konw why!?

Answer (score 1):

Use getItemCount() method of your CustomAdapter4 class. Reference here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter#getitemcount

Answer (score 1):

You need to override this method in adapter

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return dataSet.size(); // Where dataSet is the list of your items (data_list in your code)
}
```

Then you can check if recycler is empty this way

```
if (adapter.getItemCount() == 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `public int getItemCount()`

> **Description** : Returns the total number of items in the data set held by the adapter.
>
> **Returns**: The total number of items in this adapter

Here's an example :

```
if ( adapter.getItemCount() == 0 ) {
            // show your dialog 
}
```